# How to dynamically generate a Phoenix controller function with a map argument?

Tags: macros, elixir, phoenix-framework

So I'm using Phoenix 1.3, and I created a macro to generate a function and inject it into a controller.

Based on the number I pass in, I want it to generate a map with that many parameters that are named "id1", "id2", etc. all the way up to "id#{number}". This map will be part of the argument list along with the usual Phoenix "conn".

So I want to generate a method like this to be pattern matched against and "some stuff" can be executed:

```
def index(conn, %{"id1" => id1, "id2" => id2}) do
  # some stuff
end
```

when I call the macro `create_some_function_by_number("index", 2)`.

My macro looks something like:

```
defmacro create_some_function_by_number(name, num) do
    params =
      for n <- 1..num, do: %{"id#{n}" => Macro.var(:"id#{n}", nil)}
      |> Map.new

    quote do
      def unquote(:"#{name}")(unquote(Macro.escape(params)) do
         # some code here for the index action
      end
    end
  end
```

1) How do I inject the "conn" into the function head so it can be pattern matched against?

2) Is this the correct way to create the map to be pattern matched against?

Comment: Using a macro sound like premature optimization. Could you solve your problem by iterating the tuples in the params map?

Comment: @J.RandomCoder - Do you have a link or snippet or further detail on what you mean by " iterating the tuples in the params map"?

Comment: Also, I'd still like to learn more about metaprogramming, so I'd like to have the answer to this ? be in line with that.

Comment: I mean you could dynamically react to the number of "items" (tuples) in the map at runtime instead of defining functions for any meaningful number of parameters at compile time. The following snippet will work no matter how many tuples in the first parameter: `Enum.map(%{"id1": 23, "id2": 42}, fn {key,value} -> IO.puts("#{key}: #{value}") end)`.

Comment: I was hoping to do the exact pattern matching on the function head because it seems like that would also let me more easily take advantage of the action_fallback for error handling.  So if it didn't match `def some_dynamic_fund(conn, %{"id1" => id1, "id2" => id2}  = params), do: "hello" `, then it would naturally fall back to the error.

Comment: Actually, researching further, I'm not sure I can use macros in this way ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can definitely use macros in this way, you probably should not. Here is a working solution with comments:

```
defmodule MyMacro do
  defmacro create_some_function_by_number(name, num, do: block) do
    params =
      for n <- 1..num do
        {"id#{n}", Macro.var(:"id#{n}", nil)}
      end

    # We can't call Macro.escape because it is for escaping values.
    # In this case, we have a mixture of values "id#{n}" and
    # expressions "Macro.var(...)", so we build the map AST by hand.
    pattern =
      {:%{}, [], params}

    conn =
      Macro.var(:conn, nil)

    quote do
      def unquote(:"#{name}")(unquote(conn), unquote(pattern)) do
        unquote(block)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyExample do
  import MyMacro

  create_some_function_by_number :index, 2 do
    {conn, id1 + id2}
  end
end

IO.inspect MyExample.index(:conn, %{"id1" => 1, "id2" => 2})
```

As you can see, macros can make the code harder to understand. If you can solve it at runtime, it should definitely be preferred.